# Laravel - Error al intentar crear esta migración

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7, laravel-8, migration

Buenas tengo 2 tablas que tienes sus propios id, la tabla "ingredientes" seria la tabla padre y la tabla "recetas_ingredientes" quiero relacionar el campo "real_id" de la tabla ingredientes con el campo "ingrediente_id" de la tabla recetas_ingredientes.

Como podeis ver los declaro integer y unsigned en ambos lados pero me da un fallo de constraint key que no consigo ver el problema.

**Migration 1**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ingredientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('real_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('descripcion');
        $table->integer('orden')->default('10');
        $table->boolean('activo')->default('1');
        $table->boolean('mostrar')->default('1');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Migration 2**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recetas_ingredientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('receta_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('ingrediente_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('receta_id')->references('id')->on('recetas')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ingrediente_id')->references('real_id')->on('ingredientes')->unsigned();
    });
}
```

**El error que recibo es este**

PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1822 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'recetas_ingredientes_ingrediente_id_foreign' in the referenced table 'ingredientes'")

En esta linia

```
 $table->foreign('ingrediente_id')->references('real_id')->on('ingredientes')->unsigned();
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel usas?

Comment: Ese error se da, por lo general, al querer crear una tabla con columnas de referencia, primero que las tablas a las que hace referencia. Te recomendaría verificaras las fechas y las horas en las que estás tratando de crear dichas migraciones y no sea que estás creando primero recetas_ingredientes y luego ingredientes.

Comment: Uso laravel 8, primero creo ingredientes y luego recetas_ingredientes

Comment: Y la tabla "recetas" sí existe? Quítale el `unsigned` a la declaración de las FK a ver si cambia el error

Comment: Oh, ahora acabo de darme cuenta: no tienes indexada la columna referenciada. Debes crear un índice en `ingredientes.real_id`. MySQL crea el índice en la tabla hija, pero no creará automáticamente el análogo en la referenciada

Comment: es decir a real_id le cambio el ->unsigned() por unique()?

Comment: Primero haz la prueba creando un índice en el campo `real_id` de la tabla  `ingredientes`. No puedes apuntar una llave foránea a un campo no indexado.